# Why do I get "content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate" on IE 11?

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, certificate, maps

I have just implemented Google maps via IFRAME on one of my websites, here is an example:

http://www.musicianspage.com/musicians/Fabrizio/

But where the map is supposed to show, on Internet Explorer 11 I get the following error:

"Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate"

Why is that? Isn't Google's content coming via SSL with a valid certificate??!!

Any thoughts and ideas how to solve this is very welcome. I would really like users using IE 11 with default settings being able to see the map without having to mess around with IE certificate settings!

Thank you in advance for any help.

Best,
Fab.

Comment: Works fine in my IE 11.

Comment: did you find any solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technical but late and true answer is:

> The issue occurs because SSL 2.0 and TLS 1.2 are not compatible with
> each other in Internet Explorer 9 and later versions.

So you need to add the website to your `Trusted sites` through the `Internet Options`.
As you mentioned in your question. A workaround isn't possible.

Note: I know you probably use the new `Edge-Browser` but for the sake of completeness I wrote this answer, if it can even help one of you, it's fair enough. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer after so many years!